What specific dark curse was on the ring that Dumbledore put on?
When Dumbledore put the ring on, a dark curse was activated. I looked through Pottermore and couldn't find the specific curse that was inflicted on Dumbledore. What was the dark curse on the ring?

Unknown. Just a "powerful curse" - https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Curse_on_Marvolo_Gaunt%27s_Ring
